For a singleTop activity, the previous instance is reused, even though the activity was not at top of the stack
`The LauncherActivity is the first screen in Homescreen. I am trying to understand if singleTop or singleTask would be the right launchmode.
The idea is to avoid creating multiple activity instances in all transitions to Homescreen.
The activity configuration in Manifest is -
<activity
    android:name=".ui.LauncherActivity"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:stateNotNeeded="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER_APP" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.AppDrawerActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

The activity can be triggered only from a non-acitivty application, which belongs to a different package from LauncherActivity. It is launched like below-
private void startHomeActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Constants.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(Constants.HOME_PACKAGE_NAME,
            Constants.HOME_ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME));
    intent.addFlags(Constants.SETTINGS_HOME_AND_ALL_APPS_FLAG);
    mContext.startActivityAsUser(intent, UserHandle.CURRENT);
}

Observation:
Currently singleTop is set as launchmode for the LauncherActivity. Please note that, AppDrawerActivity is another acitivty, which belong to Homescreen application package.
The transition is done as below-

Reboot the system, current screen is Homescreen(LauncherActivity).
Switch to AppDrawerActivity
Switch to HVAC application from AppDrawerActivity

at this point the activity dump shows the stack as below. Here, we can see that in task#1200003, AppDrawerActivity is on the top of the stack.
Task display areas in top down Z order:
TaskDisplayArea DefaultTaskDisplayArea
  mPreferredTopFocusableRootTask=Task{82141e #1200004 type=standard A=1210072:com.apps.hvac U=12 visible=true visibleRequested=true mode=fullscreen translucent=false sz=1}
  mLastFocusedRootTask=Task{82141e #1200004 type=standard A=1210072:com.apps.hvac U=12 visible=true visibleRequested=true mode=fullscreen translucent=false sz=1}
  Application tokens in top down Z order:
  * Task{82141e #1200004 type=standard A=1210072:com.apps.hvac U=12 visible=true visibleRequested=true mode=fullscreen translucent=false sz=1}
    bounds=[0,0][1280,720]
    * ActivityRecord{63ba8ca u12 com.apps.hvac/.ui.HvacLandingActivity t1200004}
  * Task{57a2911 #1 type=home ?? U=0 visible=false visibleRequested=false mode=fullscreen translucent=true sz=2}
    bounds=[0,0][1280,720]
    * Task{4bd5acd #1200003 type=home A=1201000:com.apps.homescreen U=12 rootTaskId=1 visible=false visibleRequested=false mode=fullscreen translucent=true sz=2}
      bounds=[0,0][1280,720]
      * ActivityRecord{34c92b u12 com.apps.homescreen/.ui.AppDrawerActivity t1200003}
      * ActivityRecord{d1d210e u12 com.apps.homescreen/.ui.LauncherActivity t1200003}
    * Task{4089178 #2 type=home A=10132:com.android.car.provision U=0 rootTaskId=1 visible=false visibleRequested=false mode=fullscreen translucent=true sz=1}
      bounds=[0,0][1280,720]
      * ActivityRecord{6be6283 u0 com.android.car.provision/.DefaultActivity t2}`

The we click on Home button, which is handled in a different non-acitivty application. Now the stack looks as below.
Task display areas in top down Z order:
TaskDisplayArea DefaultTaskDisplayArea
  mPreferredTopFocusableRootTask=Task{57a2911 #1 type=home ?? U=0 visible=true visibleRequested=true mode=fullscreen translucent=false sz=2}
  mLastFocusedRootTask=Task{57a2911 #1 type=home ?? U=0 visible=true visibleRequested=true mode=fullscreen translucent=false sz=2}
  Application tokens in top down Z order:
  * Task{57a2911 #1 type=home ?? U=0 visible=true visibleRequested=true mode=fullscreen translucent=false sz=2}
    bounds=[0,0][1280,720]
    * Task{4bd5acd #1200003 type=home A=1201000:com.apps.homescreen U=12 rootTaskId=1 visible=true visibleRequested=true mode=fullscreen translucent=false sz=1}
      bounds=[0,0][1280,720]
      * ActivityRecord{d1d210e u12 com.apps.homescreen/.ui.LauncherActivity t1200003}
    * Task{4089178 #2 type=home A=10132:com.android.car.provision U=0 rootTaskId=1 visible=false visibleRequested=false mode=fullscreen translucent=true sz=1}
      bounds=[0,0][1280,720]
      * ActivityRecord{6be6283 u0 com.android.car.provision/.DefaultActivity t2}
  * Task{82141e #1200004 type=standard A=1210072:com.apps.hvac U=12 visible=false visibleRequested=false mode=fullscreen translucent=true sz=1}
    bounds=[0,0][1280,720]
    * ActivityRecord{63ba8ca u12 com.apps.hvac/.ui.HvacLandingActivity t1200004}

public static final int SETTINGS_HOME_AND_ALL_APPS_FLAG = 0x14000000;

private void launchAppDrawerScreen() {
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_MAIN);
      intent.addCategory(Constants.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
      intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(Constants.HOME_PACKAGE_NAME,
              Constants.APP_DRAWER_ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME));
      intent.addFlags(Constants.SETTINGS_HOME_AND_ALL_APPS_FLAG); // launchFlags
      mContext.startActivityAsUser(intent, UserHandle.CURRENT);
}


Manifest declaration:
<activity
    android:name=".ui.AppDrawerActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.bosch.apps.homescreen.ACTION_APP_GRID" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

**Could anyone please help to understand these points?

As per the document, when a singleTop acitivty is started, if it is not at the top of the task, it should be recreated. In this case,
AppDrawerActivity was at the top of task. But still why the previous instance of LauncherActivity was reused instead of recreating it?

In this case which launchmode would be ideal in between singleTop and singleTask?**


`

Read this post https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

It is possible that android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" is causing the problem. Try removing this and see if the behaviour is different. In your second task list, the task has been stripped back to the root Activity (LauncherActivity) and AppDrawerActivity is gone. This may also be due to the <activity> declaration for AppDrawerActivity. Please edit the question and post the manifest declaration for AppDrawerActivity.

@David Wasser
I have added the declaration of AppDrawerActivity. I had already tried removing the clearTaskOnLaunch flag, but the same behavior was seen.

Do you have your app registered as a HOME screen replacement? When the user presses HOME button, it returns to your app, right?

@David Wasser, Yes right. The LauncherActivity is shown at Homescreen.

Is there any code in AppDrawerActivity that would cause it to finish in this case? Post the code you use to launch AppDrawerActivity please.

There are some conditions where Android will strip a task down to the root Activity, which is what you are seeing. This behaviour can be seen when using launch mode singleTask. Even though you didn't declare this launch mode, it may be possible that Android assumes all HOME screens should be handled as if the launch mode is singleTask.  Here is an issue from a long time ago that describes a similar problem: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36921210. If you look at comment #2 in this issue, this is exactly what you are seeing (behaves like singleTop with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

If AppDrawerActivity is launched, for example, with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY, then as soon as you press the HOME key, AppDrawerActivity would automatically be finished by Android. So there could be a lot of reasons why you are seeing what you are seeing.

@DavidWasser, Thank you for the points. I just added the manifest declaration of AppDrawer activity and how it is launched. I would like to mention that the appDrawer activity is also launched from a different applicaton SystemUI, like LauncherAcitivity is launched. And I did not understand the purpose of the flag- SETTINGS_HOME_AND_ALL_APPS_FLAG. Could you pls help to understand the issue?

Well, I'm even more confused. Now you need to show the code that runs when the HOME button is pressed and show how the LauncherActivity is launched. Anyway, SETTINGS_HOME_AND_ALL_APPS_FLAG has a value of 0x14000000. This represents these 2 flags combined: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK = 0x10000000.and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP = 0x04000000. Also this code is full of unecessary stuff, like setting ACTION and CATEGORY when you create an explicit Intent is generally not needed, but this is probably not relevant to your problem, but confuses things.

You need to set FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK when you launch an Intent from a non-Activity context. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP makes sure that if there is already an instance of AppDrawerActivity in the stack, the stack will be cleared back to (and including) this instance of AppDrawerActivity and a new instance of AppDrawerActivity will be created. But that doesn't explain what you are seeing.

@DavidWasser, The function startHomeActivity() is used to launch the LauncherActivity. The same is mentioned in the main question. Could you pls check it? That also uses the combined flag.

Well, finally! This explains the behaviour!
public static final int SETTINGS_HOME_AND_ALL_APPS_FLAG = 0x14000000;

private void startHomeActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Constants.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(Constants.HOME_PACKAGE_NAME,
        Constants.HOME_ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME));
    intent.addFlags(Constants.SETTINGS_HOME_AND_ALL_APPS_FLAG);
    mContext.startActivityAsUser(intent, UserHandle.CURRENT);
}

You are starting LauncherActivity with the following flags in the Intent:
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK =  0x10000000;
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP = 0x04000000;

Because FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is set, this will remove any Activity that is in the task on top of the existing LauncherActivity. This is why AppDrawerActivity is removed from the task when you press the HOME button.
Since the manifest declaration for LauncherActivity has launchMode="singleTop", the combination of CLEAR_TOP and SINGLE_TOP tells Android to remove any activities on top of the existing LauncherActivity and to reuse the existing instance of LauncherActivity.
This all works as documented and as designed. If this isn't what you want, you will need to explain what you want to happen and I can suggest a way to achieve that.

Thanks a lot. Now I understand how it is done. Could you pls help me to understand this issue in my system. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78560238/widget-is-not-updated-after-widget-update-is-stopped-and-started-again
